# How do you enable Azure diagnostics when uploading a .cspkg file?

Tags: azure-diagnostics

When I "publish" a web role through Visual Studio, diagnostics gets enabled. If I upload a .cspkg file through the portal, diagnostics is not enabled.

Is there something else you need to do to get diagnostics turned on when uploading a file outside of VS?

Comment: What version of the Azure SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on 2.5 you will need to enable the diagnostics your self

here is a link to an msdn blog that describes how (using powershell)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2014/12/02/windows-azure-diagnostics-upgrading-from-azure-sdk-2-4-to-azure-sdk-2-5.aspx

You need to scroll to the section on "Enabling diagnostics extension through PowerShell"